# Line plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do you do a line plot of a matrix such as A=rand(5) without using surf?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot every column separately in a 2D plot, you just write

```
plot(A)
```

If you want to make a 3D plot with lines, you could write:

```
[xx,yy] = ndgrid(1:6,1:5);
A = [A;NaN(1,size(A,2))]; %# add NaNs so that the lines will be plotted separately
plot3(xx(:),yy(:),A(:)) %# use plot3(xx(:),yy(:),A(:),'.') if you want to plot dots instead of lines.
```