# Making plot of matrix entries using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I've got a matrix A=magic(4) and wish to plot the values using plot3(1:4,1:4,A,'ks'). But that plots everything on the diagonal and not where they actually are relative to the other values in the matrix. How do I do that? I'm sure it's pretty easy but I'm new to matlab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line plots in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169263/line-plots-in-matlab). Duplicate user, near duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate matrices for the `X` and `Y` coordinates of the plotted points:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:4);  %# X and Y are each 4-by-4 matrices, just like A
plot3(X,Y,A,'ks');      %# Make a 3-D plot of the points
```

You could also plot a surface instead of a set of points using the function [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html), in which case the need to use [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate the `X` and `Y` coordinates is optional:

```
surf(X,Y,A);      %# Use the 4-by-4 matrices from MESHGRID
surf(1:4,1:4,A);  %# Pass 1-by-4 vectors instead
surf(A);          %# Automatically uses 1:4 for each set of coordinates
```

Answer (score 1):

@gnovice would be my answer.

I'll add that sometimes a simple imagesc is nice for visualizing a matrix:

```
imagesc(A)
```